# Handling variable String zeros in IF condition in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm going through a condition where I can receive any number of zeros (upto 10 zeros) in json request (all in `String` format). Sometimes only 1 zero, other times 2 or 3 or more, but it is guaranteed that it will be zeros only.

I'm unable to handle this situation in and `if{}` condition.

description:

```
// zero is the api variable which can contain any number of zeros upto 10.
```

what I can think of doing is using 10 || conditions in if{} check.

```
if (zero.equals("0") || zero.equals("00") || zero.equals("000") || ...)
```

which is nowhere seems logical and efficient.

So, how should I handle this scenario?

Comment: use `zero.contains("0")`

Comment: Use a regex: `if(zero.trim().matches("^0+$")){}`: that checks if `zero` only contains one or more zeros

Comment: @Lino that would match `"1000"` as well.

Comment: @Lino contains is not enough for this scenario.

Comment: You said "it will always be zeros only", which means that your if statement is always true, which means that you don't need such an if statement.

Comment: Actually @Sweeper is right. So the question now becomes, what are you trying to do with that `if`? Are you testing the library and check that the condition holds true or what?

Comment: @Sweeper But it's in String format, and that can vary too in number.

Comment: Do you actually want to know how many 0s there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-):

```
// If zero contains between 1 and 10 zeroes
if (zero.matches("0{1,10}")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Suspending judgment until OP clarifies, but in the meantime notice that this would match something like `"1000"` as well.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It would not, `matches` will prepend `^` at the start and append `$` at the end, so the only possible character in the string is a `0`

Comment: Thanks @Jesper. It solves my scenario currently. Can it be more generic? What If number of zeros is not fixed. Say it can go upto 15 or 16 then?

Comment: @Jabongg If you want to match an arbitrary number of zeroes, (1 or more) the regex would be `0+` (the `+` means: one or more). See the documentation of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn about regular expressions in Java.

Comment: If it is wrapped in `^` and `$`, would not a simple `matches("0+")` work?

Comment: @Lino I can't find that in the docs. Can you please point me to where it says that? Genuinely curious, not trying to be a smartass.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  matches: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--   vs find (which matches substrings)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `String.matches()` delegates to `Pattern.matches()` which internally uses `Matcher.matches()` and there you see: *Returns: true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern*

Answer (score 1):

The ugly thing about this method, is just that it could throw a `NumberFormatException`, when input is incorrect (not a number).

But well, 10 or 1 zeroes, don't care how many, the numeric value of a "0" filled string will always be 0.

```
try
{
  if (Integer.parseInt(zero) == 0)
  {
    //do your things
  }
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
  //handle it when it's not a number
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `BigInteger` to account for bigger numbers and then compare to `BigInteger.ZERO`

Comment: @Lino, it says that max number of zeros is just ten, so we may be OK with letting it fail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming nothing but the "zero" can start with a zero, so code like

```
if (zero.charAt(0) == '0') {
    ...
}
```

Should be what you need.

If string can be empty, then you'll need

```
!zero.isEmpty() && zero.charAt(0) == '0'
```

to avoid exceptions

Alternatively, you can write

```
if (zero.startsWith("0")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `startsWith` is safer, because it will work with empty strings, where as the first example will throw an exception

Comment: @Lino, yes, I didn't consider empty string. My assumption was that an empty string will be handled somewhere up from where this condition is placed. One can also prepend the `!zero.isEmpty()` before checking first char.

Comment: The post does not say if "number" means "integer", otherwise there could be `0.5`. So this is a bit brittle.

Comment: @Thilo, yes, if number is a javascript Number (i.e. the Double), then it's better to either parse double or iterate all chars instead of checking just one: `zero.chars().allMatch(c -> c == '0'))`. I won't keep adding to my answer though, leave it in comments.